# Social Science Trade Book

Tags: references

I am looking for a book (not textbook) to use in an undergraduate statistics course. I would like to find a book with a clear central thesis relying largely on statistical reasoning and evidence to support the thesis. I would use the book to motivate discussions on measurement, research design, validity, reliability, sampling, statistics etc. In the past, I've used Putnam's Bowling Alone and Gilbert's Stumbling on Happiness. I've considered Sunstein & Thaler's Nudge, various Malcom Gladwell books, Kahneman's Thinking Fast and Slow. Ideally, I find a book with broad appeal and plenty of social science (perhaps conflicting) to draw upon. A bonus would be a book with supporting, publicly available data set. Ideas?

Comment: In my opinion, under no circumstances should you use a Malcom Gladwell book for anything in undergrad as a cautionary tale of how NOT to think. (And maybe setting a bonfire.) None of the books that you listed strike me as stats books at all. To get more precise answer, I think you should be more specific with your question. What level undergrad are you referring to? What background/pre-requisites do these students have? What is the goal of the course, i.e. general information or as a pre-requisite for other courses?

Comment: I am not looking for a stats book, as I note in my original post. I want a social science book to serve as a supplement to a traditional stats textbook. The students are 2nd and 3rd year. I assume no background in quantitative methods. For some students, this may be their last class as undergraduates in quantitative methods. For others, it is a prereq to a more advanced statistics course. The overall course goals are statistical literacy and applied statistical analysis.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider "The Bell Curve" by Herrnstein and Murray. They used the NLSY data, which is publicly available. The main book argues their thesis, while there are a couple of hundred pages of statistical analysis in the appendix. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bell_Curve

It starts off fairly sensibly, they talk about 'cognitive segregation', that you tend to associate with people who are of similar intelligence to yours. Then it starts to get more, errrmmm..., interesting, until the final chapter where they suggest that people with low IQs should live on reservations.

There's a lot more learning done when you pick holes in a book that you disagree with than find one where you nod along the whole time. The book can be critiqued on several levels - you can discuss their conclusions with no knowledge of statistics, for example from a sociological perspective, or you can delve into the models.

It's a little old, and I don't know how much it costs. There were at least two books that came out as direct responses to it as well.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I agree that students may learn more if a critical posture is easier to get to. Do you remember the "response" book titles?

Comment: @DBK Thanks. One was The Bell Curve Wars: http://www.amazon.com/The-Bell-Curve-Wars-Intelligence/dp/0465006930. Edit: Just found another: http://www.springer.com/statistics/social+sciences+%26+law/book/978-0-387-94986-4

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your interest is in qualitative analysis rather than quantitative, because terms such as *reliability* and *validity* are from *qualitative* analysis domain. That's why I'd suggest you to look at texts in [psychometrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychometrics#Bibliography), for instance [Michell, Joel. "Quantitative science and the definition of measurement in psychology." British Journal of Psychology 88.3 (1997): 355-383.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpsychology.okstate.edu%2Ffaculty%2Fjgrice%2Fpsyc4333%2FMichell_1997.pdf&ei=GaGZVJS_AcG-ggTep4SgBA&usg=AFQjCNG8AnFytZ2Ov0fyG_uXhljiOGWB0g&sig2=2btL10rTMKyzzkC4oABaUw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.eXY). He also has book ["Measurement in Psychology"](https://books.google.com/books?id=oNIcvjpDQeQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

There's an easier reading book on the measurement in soft subjects: DeVellis, Robert F (2003). [Scale Development: Theory and Applications](http://www.bus.ucf.edu/faculty/rfolger/file.axd?file=2012%2F11%2FDeVellis%20-%20Scale%20development.pdf) (2nd ed.). He covers validity and reliability, latent variables and such.

Comment: I've never heard of reliability and validity as being purely qualitative domains (but maybe we're meaning different things by qualitative). I find Michell's work to be possibly interesting, but very hard to read, and short on suggestions about what we should be doing.

Comment: It's not my field, but that's how I got introduced to these things in the course on qualitative analysis, along with things like factor analysis (CFA). I guess the qualitativeness comes from the domain. Measuring *happiness* is very different from measuring income. So, they came up with these quantitative techniques and math to do it, but it really is very different kind of measurement compared to physics or even economics. So, psychometrics is really the field that does this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, that's interesting. (I've just edited a book called "Quantitative research in psychology" and it has a lot on things like CFA and reliability, there's a companion called "Qualitative research in psychology" which has nothing on these things. Here, in case you're interested: http://smile.amazon.com/Quantitative-Research-Psychology-SAGE-Benchmarks/dp/1446282678/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1419360536&sr=8-1

Comment: @JeremyMiles, I added another ref. On *qualitativeness*: my background is in quantitative area, so I figured this was all *qualitative*, touchy-feely stuff, but you might be right that it should be treated as quantitative treatment of the subject. Maybe I should edit my response.

Comment: I don't think you need to edit your response, I think it's OK to cover different perspectives. I like DeVellis's book too.

Comment: I am interested in quantitative research. Validity and reliability, as applied to measurement, are important concepts in both qualitative and quantitative research. See [here](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/measure.php) for one explanation.